# Google Sheets: Conditional formatting a column of cells to an adjacent cell(column)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm very new to coding and haven't tried anything really. I did see this is possible through conditional formatting outside of the macros but it seems it only applies to the current spreadsheet and I didn't notice a way to quickly do this for all applicable cells in every sheet.

I have a spreadsheet I use for budgeting. Column B is labeled Sub-total, this is the amount that Column D(Actually Spent) is supposed to meet but not exceed. I would like the cells in column D to be the default color until it reaches the amount from the adjacent cell in column B. If the amount goes over the number in the adjacent column B cell then i would like it to be red.

This should apply to every sheet in the workbook and i would like it to do this automatically without prompting anything other than opening the workbook.

Also, when I'm done budgeting for that pay period if I've gone over budget I change the tab's color to red, if I'm within budget the tab is black.

Coding is something I've wanted to learn and i think this is a good place to start.

The below link is an example of a budget. With "cell phone" being too high", "Gas/Fuel" being correct, and "Grocery" being under.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17lUuwdjfPz17_gkckofgW8pnqGMvBlqeyN8d8xq2HxY/edit?usp=sharing

### Edit: I figured out the conditional formatting.

```
**Red:** Custom formula is =D3>1*B3 for range D3:D72
**Empty:** Cell is empty for range D3:D72
**Green:** Custom formula is =D3=B3 for range D3:D72
```

**My next question would be how do I make it so this is applied to all of the sheets instead of just the current sheet?**

Answer (score 0):

I went the route of recording a macro while applying the conditional formatting that I wanted. It came out long and clunky but I've reduced it down to the following script that does what I want it to do quickly and efficiently. It would be cool to have this applied to all spreadsheets in the workbook but the keyboard shortcut is easy enough to use. I will just want to do this before I use each spreadsheet on my phone.

```
function ZeroBalance1() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   var conditionalFormatRules = 
spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getConditionalFormatRules();

  conditionalFormatRules.splice(conditionalFormatRules.length - 1, 1, 
SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
  .setRanges([spreadsheet.getRange('D3:D72')])
  .whenFormulaSatisfied('=D3>1*B3')
  .setBackground('#FF0000')
  .build());

  conditionalFormatRules.push(SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
  .setRanges([spreadsheet.getRange('D3:D72')])
  .whenCellEmpty()
   .build());

  conditionalFormatRules.push(SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
  .setRanges([spreadsheet.getRange('D3:D72')])
    .whenFormulaSatisfied('=D3=B3')
  .setBackground('#00FF00')
   .build());

  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setConditionalFormatRules(conditionalFormatRules);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I reworked your code a bit and came up with this script that loops through all sheets in your spreadsheet and adds the conditional formatting to all of them at once. Basically, with [getSheets()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets) you can get an array of all the sheets in the spreadsheet, and with a `for` loop you can create the rules for all sheets:

```
function ZeroBalance() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheets = spreadsheet.getSheets();
  var column = 4;
  // Loop through each sheet in the file
  for(var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    var sheet = sheets[i];
    var range = sheet.getRange('D3:D72');
    // Create conditional rules
    var turnRed = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
      .setRanges([range])
      .whenFormulaSatisfied('=D3>1*B3')
      .setBackground('#FF0000')
      .build();
    var turnDefault = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
      .setRanges([range])
      .whenCellEmpty()
      .build();
    var turnGreen = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
      .setRanges([range])
      .whenFormulaSatisfied('=D3=B3')
      .setBackground('#00FF00') // Green
      .build();
    var conditionalFormatRules = [turnRed, turnDefault, turnGreen];
    // Add conditional rules to the sheet
    sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(conditionalFormatRules);
  }
}
```

Let me know if that works for you.